# Item with ListView in ListView android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listView that contains each of its items another listView. My problem is that for each listView each item, only one item is displayed. I do not understand why?

Here's what I want vs what I have:

[image: capture image]

In adapter of my first ListView I realize a setAdapter for each of its items:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    final PlanningViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_planning, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new PlanningViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textViewPlanningMonth = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewPlanningMonth);
        viewHolder.textViewPlanningDayValue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewPlanningDayValue);
        viewHolder.listViewPlanningContentForDay = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewPlanningContentForDay);

        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (PlanningViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    Planning planning = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.textViewPlanningMonth.setText(planning.getMonth());
    viewHolder.textViewPlanningDayValue.setText(planning.getDay());
    viewHolder.listViewPlanningContentForDay.setAdapter(new PlanningContentAdapter(context, planning.getListContentPlanning()));
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot have a listview in a scrollable view - either ListView, either ScrollView

Comment: can you post code from layout xml file here??

Comment: Ok, I understand. I just block size listView items with a value instead of wrap-content, and my items are displayed.

Comment: As you are showing multiple listview's so you have to set your each listview height fix so that it will get some space to add the items and show it and also allow to scroll.

Comment: you have to make your parent listview row height wrap_content and calculate the height of your inner layout basis of height and the numbers of row in it (i.e, inner listview new height = inner listview row layout height * numbers of row).

Comment: In effect @Bazinga, you have absolutely right. I think it's still a shame that this case is not managed by the android framwork.

Comment: you can change height using layout param for that only you have your own calculation to pass new height. @lopez.mikhael

Comment: Is it possible to do it in the XML file? @Bazinga

Comment: no you have to calculate this new height in your java code. you have your array, you have your base adaptor, you have layout params. so change height programattically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my probleme with this solution :

```
LayoutParams params = viewHolder.listViewPlanningContentForDay.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (int)((context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_item_planning_content) + 
    context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.space_item_planning_content)) * 
    planning.getListContentPlanning().size());
viewHolder.listViewPlanningContentForDay.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I calculate the height of my inner layout basis of height, and the numbers of row in it:

> ListView new height = (inner listview row layout height + height
>   separator) * numbers of row

I recorded the dimensions in `dimens.xml` file for compatibility with all devices:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="height_item_planning_content">47dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="space_item_planning_content">1dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

** Thanks BaZinga for your help